# Alternatives to polling for a python daemon

Tags: python, daemon, polling

I have a python daemon that checks for PPS (Packets Per Second) on certain ports and when the PPS exceeds certain threshold, It notifies the remote server with port numbers that are causing the burst, my current approach is to check the PPS for every 30 seconds inside a while loop. Considering the limited resources on the device (linux kernel based switch) where this daemon is running, my current approach is hogging the CPU, Is there any alternative for this ?

I've checked out Observer design pattern, but still, in order to fire the event, my source object will have to poll in some or other way!

I'm kinda stuck in a loop, I appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Is the loop causing cpu hog? If so - why is the loop causing CPU hog? How are you "sleeping" for 30 seconds?. Please update with more info.

Comment: kumar_m_kiran, in order to capture the PPS at every port of the switch, my daemon runs a command (show hardware internal buffer info pkt-stats detail) and parses the output. Though I'm sleeping for 30(using time.sleep) seconds, when I run this command and parse the output, my cpu utilization spikes and it's bad when the switch is busy serving huge traffic, which is the reason I'm trying to further optimize the approach. Hope it gives more info !

Comment: By parsing do you mean regex? Then I think you need to check python api which can directly give these data as part of the structure. Basically my worry is now with that of parser - Because most probably your daemon approach is fine I believe.

Comment: Kumar_m_kiran, keeping the parser aside, I'm concerned about the polling itself, let's say if the burst roughly happens once in ten polls, then I'm technically wasting the resources for the other nine polls, I'm wondering if I can evade these non-burst polls by some other non-polling approach to the problem. Closest solution I found is to have an event trigger that can detect the burst, but even in this case, I don't see how can the event trigger can work without using polling in some or other way :-|